Digest Mismatch when signing with pdfbox and GCP KMS
I'm trying to follow this guide to sign a pdf with Google Clouds KMS. When testing with pdfsig I get:
  - Total document signed
  - Signature Validation: Digest Mismatch.

Adobe Acrobat says:
Signature is invalid:
Source of Trust obtained from Adobe Approved Trust List (AATL).
    Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed
    Signer's identity is valid
    The signature includes an embedded timestamp.
> Signature Details
    Last Checked: 2024.12.18 11:42:15 +02'00'
    Field: Signature1 (invisible signature)

But I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong? The full code is available here, with a signed pdf in issue 1.

Analyzing your example PDF, I see 2 issues:
Encapsulated content
The signature container you create encapsulates the data to sign. This is wrong (as far as the PDF signature specification is concerned) and also makes no sense: After all, the CMS container is embedded into the PDF, so why should this embedded signature container in turn have an embedded copy of the PDF data it is embedded in?
Thus, replace
CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, true); 

by
CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false); 

in CreateSignatureBase.sign.
Non-decryptable signature
When I attempt to decrypt the naked signature bytes using the public key of your signer certificate, the result neither ends with a 0xBC byte nor does it constitute a padded DigestInfo object. Thus, it is neither a complete RSASSA-PSS signature nor is it an old-style RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 one.
Something like this usually indicates that the public key in the alleged signer certificate does not match the private key used for signing.
Thus, please check the key you use for signing.

Thanks! Do you think the certificate was created incorrectly? (i.e., is it related to the CSR?). If not, what else can I try to get this to work?

"Do you think the certificate was created incorrectly?" - That would be my guess, yes. I obviously don't have access to your private key, so I cannot test. In your place I'd first check whether the public key in the certificate actually matches the public key associated with your private key. If they don't match, compare them both with the public key in the CSR. If public keys in csr and cert differ, your CA did something wrong. If public keys in csr google cloud kms differ, you did something wrong.


"If public keys in csr and cert differ, your CA did something wrong"

They differ, so I'll follow up with them. Thanks so, so much!
